# Interconnection clarification?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

I just want to clear what seems to be a bit confusing to me with quantum gates and their corresponding output. below are 3 scenarios implementing two hadamard gates

1. two hadamard gates on one qubit 
   [image: two hadamard gates on one qubit]
2. Hadamard gates on two qubits 
   [image: Hadamard gates on two qubits]
3. Interconnected Hadamard gates on two qubits 
   [image: Interconnected Hadamard gates on two qubits]

with the first scenario, I am sure the case is
$$ H \cdot H = H^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}. \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1&0 \\
0&1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = I $$

with the second scenario, I am sure the case is
$$H \otimes H = H_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix} \otimes  \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{-1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{-1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{-1}{2}&\frac{-1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{-1}{2}&\frac{-1}{2}&\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

What seems to be the case with scenario 3 or what does the interconnection do to the qubits?

> **P.S** I haven't noticed Hadamard gates in a circuit as in scenario 3 but have seen Pauli-X and Pauli-Z gates used in this manner, for example the [magic-state-distillation](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,1,%22Z%22,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B1,%22Z%22,1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,1,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,1,1,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,1,1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,1,%22Z%22,1,%22Z%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,%22Z%22,1,1,%22Z%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,%22Z%22,1,%22Z%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,%22Z%22,%22Z%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D,%5B1,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D,%5B1,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B1,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,1,1,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,%22X%22,1,1,%22X%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,1,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B%22Z%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%22Chance4%22%5D,%5B%22Amps1%22,%22%7C0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80%7C%22,%22%7C0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80%7C%22,%22%7C0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80%7C%22,%22%7C0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80%7C%22%5D%5D%7D) on [Quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenario 3 does not make sense to me. You should provide a reference, if any.

I think you have been confused by controlled gates like CNOT, which is a Pauli-X gate applied to a target qubit, provided that the state of the control qubit is $|1\rangle$.

Comment: Hi Michele, did you have a look at the `magic-state-distillation` on quirk from the **P.S** with series of interconnected Pauli-Z gates

Comment: Dear Linker, can you provide a link about that?

Comment: just click on `magic-state-distillation` from the question to see it (right in the **P.S**)

Comment: I am sorry but nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: that feels weird, maybe you should try using a different browser or go to https://algassert.com/quirk and select it

Comment: Thank you for the link. In that circuit there is no gate like the one of your scenario 3. Instead, there are controlled gates (read the description of the X-Axis Control in the Toolbox 2, located under the circuit).

Comment: Hi Michele, you were right. It turned out I just got confused visually, the other gates were perfectly arranged across the line from the control gate(had to move all of them apart before I noticed). thanks